# removal of for loop from this code

Tags: matlab, optimization, image-processing, vectorization

I have a problem.

I have two matrix nbd_new and nbd_old which stores the linear index nos of a 2D matrix like phi_new and phi_old. Both phi_old & phi_new are of the same size. What I need to do is to calculate all the positions that are in the set nbd_new but not in the set nbd_old. Then for each such position I have to update the phi_new in this way : If phi_old for that position is larger than 0, then put phi_new at that position = width+1 else put phi_new at that position = -(width+1)

I have written a code like this :

```
    C = setdiff(nbd_new,nbd_old);
    for k=1:length(C)
        if phi_old(C(k))>0
            phi_new(C(k))=(width+1);
        else
            phi_new(C(k))=-(width+1);
        end
    end
```

This code works but is extremely slow due to the loops and if-then-else statement. Can this code be optimized any further ?

Thanks all in advance !!

EDIT: Please do check that phi_old and phi_new are both 2-D matrix's and the matrix C is the set of linear indexing (positions) of this matrix's. I am sorry if I was not clear beforehand. By mistake, I wrote u instead of phi. Both are same.

Comment: The code may also be slow if `u_new` isn't initialized beforehand.

Comment: Please check the edits & u_new or phi_new in this case is indeed initialized.

Comment: You're not actually using the value of C, just it's length.  Is that intentional?

Comment: @Peter Yes it is intentional indeed. C contains the linear index or positions of the 2-D matrix phi_old and phi_new only whose values are I am going to compare & change. I run the loop from 1 to the length of C by using a variable k. Then I use k to access the desired elements of the 2-D matrix phi_old & phi_new. Got it ?

Comment: No.  If C has linear indices in it (let's say [3 9 17]), then k iterates from 1:3, and you refer to phi_new at (1), (2), and (3).  What's the setdiff for if you ignore the results?

Comment: You are right. I made a mistake. I corrected it again. It should have been C(k). Now I hope my code is correct .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not need for a loop, use [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html):

```
phi_new = zeros(size(phi_old)); % preallocate memory
phi_new(C(phi_old(C)>0)) =   (width+1);
phi_new(C(phi_old(C)<0)) = - (width+1);
```

Comment: I am sorry for the misunderstanding  but could you please recheck my edited question . I made a mistake and have corrected it. The matrix u or phi(in this case) is actually a two-dimensional matrix and C stores the linear index positions of this matrices.

Comment: then just preallocate `phi_new` with the proper 2D dimensions. For example `phi_new=zeros(size(M))` see my edit to the answer...

Comment: This will work , but the thing is that I do not want to check the whole matrix phi_old . I want to check those positions of the matrix phi_old , which are stored as linear index in the matrix C. Then I want to update only those positions of the matrix phi_new , again which are stored as linear index in the matrix C.

Comment: your are not "checking" entire `phi_old` because the logical condition set is `phi_old(C)>0` as also written in my answer.

Comment: Didn't notice it. Thanks. I accepted your answer. But can you tell me whether your code will be faster than mine ?

Comment: -1: This solution fails. Note that `phi_old(C)<0` is a logical array with the same size as `C` not `phi_old`. So if, say, `C` has two elements it can only affect the first two elements of `phi_new`.

Comment: thanks for spotting this bug, I wasn't paying attention to the fact that the output of `setdiff` in this particular question can be a smaller array size. The answer, i.e. "logical indexing"  still stands, and  is now bug free.